# My RecyclerView doens't show up, it says there's no adapter, but it has

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I tried to fetch some JSON into a RecyclerView when searching for some book, all looks fine to me, but when searching the RecyclerView doens't show up.
I got this error in Logcat: `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`
that's the only thing returning an error, but I did set the `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

I'm using Google Books API to search ISBN using the phone camera, and also search book titles, authors and keywords. My aim is to show matching/similar books from search inside the RecyclerView, then the user can choose which one he wants, click and open another activity with the book info there.

**Few points to be noted:**

- I've tried all the solutions for "No adapter attached; skipping
  layout" in [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout) thread
  and all associated duplicate threads.

**Here's my Github repo:** [ISBN Scanner](https://github.com/sirbraz/ISBN_Scanner)

I don't know what to do now, I'm getting mad at this. >:(

Comment: are you sure you are getting correct response from your query?

Comment: check if this work for you [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: @windowssolution it didn't worked :(

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your repo and i have found that you are not getting booklist and getting error while parsing json data.

here what I got in exception
No value for industryIdentifiers
May be you are doing something wrong here....

```
JSONArray industryIdentifiers = book_info.getJSONArray("industryIdentifiers");
    if (industryIdentifiers.length() == 1) {
         JSONObject obj = industryIdentifiers.getJSONObject(0);
         ISBN = obj.getString("type") + ": " + obj.getString("identifier");
    } else if (industryIdentifiers.length() == 2) {
         JSONObject obj1 = industryIdentifiers.getJSONObject(0);
         JSONObject obj2 = industryIdentifiers.getJSONObject(1);
         ISBN = obj1.getString("type") + ": " + obj1.getString("identifier") + " - "
         + obj2.getString("type") + ": " + obj2.getString("identifier");
    }
```

```
Log.d("ListBook",bookList.toString());
adapter = new MyAdapter(bookList, getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

print your book list before attaching it to the adapter
also, print exception in a catch block

```
catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d("ListBook",e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what's wrong with the 'industryIdentifiers' JSON, it's working when I Click and then it opens a book info activity. But it isn't showing nothing into the RecyclerView to perform a click to the book_info. Could you please explain me more abou it?

Comment: First, print your JSON response and then get data from that response. i am pretty sure that only the data extraction part has some mistakes. your other recycler view code is perfectly fine